multivariable function is continuous iff the composition is continuous

$f : \left( {-1, 1}\right)  \times  \left( {-1, 1}\right)  \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for any continuous $r : \left\lbrack  {0, 1}\right\rbrack   \rightarrow  \left( {-1, 1}\right)  \times  \left( {-1, 1}\right)$, the composition $f \circ  r$ is continuous.

the $\Rightarrow$ part is trivial. For the $\Leftarrow$ part, How to find a $r$, or use contradiciton?

If $(a_n,b_n) \to (a,b)$ then there is a continuous function $r$ such that $r(\frac 1 n)=(a_n,b_n)$ and $r(0)=(a,b)$.
